# Как задать intent фильтр ссылок для двух приложений с одинаковым domain?

Tags: android

Есть приложение клиента и водителя. У обоих одинаковый domain example.com.
Приложение водителя должно открывать ссылку example.com и example.com/order.
Приложение клиента должно открывать ссылку example.com и example.com/advertisement.

При нажатии на ссылку example.com chooser должен предлагать открыть ссылку с помощью приложения клиента и водителя + браузер.

При нажатии на ссылку example.com/order - только приложение водителя и браузер.
При нажатии на ссылку example.com/advertisement - только приложение клиента и браузер.

пробовал различные комбинации intent фильтров, но не получилось. Пример кода:

```
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="@string/host"
                android:scheme="https"
                android:pathPrefix="/order" />

        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Напиши что конкретно не получилось: - ни одна диплинка не открывает ни одно твое приложение или все диплинки открывают все твои приложения?

Comment: второе. диплинк приложения водителя можно открыть через приложение клиента

Comment: В клиенте такой же фильтр, как и в водителеле только android:pathPrefix="/advertisement" . Можно ли как то добавить фильтра на главный экран когда пользователь переходит по ссылке без параметров? И чтобы для этой ссылки открывались два приложения.

Comment: В активити есть свойство intent (getIntent() для java) в методе onCreate() ,например ты можешь проверить, если он не равен null, то получить URI диплинки intent.data. Ну а дальше анализировать, что это за линка и что с ней делать (что то вроде if (intent.data.toString().equals("/order")). Если приложение открыто то интент придет в метод onNewIntent. И из одного приложения ты можешь открыть другое, хотя бы через имя активити, только стоит убедится что установлены оба приложения

Comment: не проще сделать redirect на сервере?